# Install Distribution on Existing Drupal INstallation

Tags: drupal

How do I Install Distribution on Existing Drupal Installation, I wanted to install OpenEnterprise on a newly installed Drupal by Softtacolous? I tried going through the themes route by did not work.

Comment: I tried manual install and I get this error Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/apps.profile.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Softacolous and do manual install and it solves it.